# Combine results from two tables into one (MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my project I am trying to combine two tables (T1 and T2) into a Query according to the example.

Table T1:

```
id_order | id_client | amount
   1     |     10    |   5
   2     |     10    |  12
   3     |     11    |   7
```

Table T2:

```
id_client| First_name| Last_name
   10    |     A     |    V
   11    |     N     |    K
   12    |     G     |    W
```

Result:

```
id_order | id_client | First_name| Last_name
   1     |     10    |    A      |     V
   2     |     10    |    A      |     V
   3     |     11    |    N      |     K
```

My code looks like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT [id_order], [id_client] FROM T1 ORDER BY [id_order]
UNION SELECT [First_name], [Last_name] FROM T2
WHERE T1.id_order = T2.id_order;
```

can anyone help please?

Comment: And you specifically want to use MySQL in conjunction with MS Access?

Comment: You need to JOIN the tables, not UNION them.  And though I'll admit I'm unfamiliar with ACCESS, I'm pretty sure you need to lose those brackets ( [] ) around the column names.  Something like SELECT t1.id_order, t1.id_client, t2.first_name, t2.last_name FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t2.id_client = t1.ID_CLIENT

Comment: well I used the brackets because I have spaces in my rows names and I can't change them any more, I tried the JOIN operator but it still throw errors

Comment: Yes, brackets are necessary when object names have spaces or punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) or are reserved words. I don't see any spaces in your field names. Also, need LEFT, RIGHT, or INNER key word with the JOIN. Are you using Access query builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT id_order, T2.id_client, First_name, Last_name 
FROM T2 INNER JOIN T1 
ON T2.id_Client = T1.id_Client
ORDER BY T1.id_order;
```

Depending on your data and what you want to retrieve, might need LEFT or RIGHT instead of INNER.

Use Access query builder to help get correct syntax. It will automatically add brackets.